# About the appstore

Tags: mac-appstore, paypal

I want to buy some apps in the appstore but I don't want to use a credit card or paypal ; is there a way to purchase apps say with a prepaid Itunes card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.

Open the iOS App Store or Mac App Store and click on “Account” from the right-hand side

If currently logged into an Apple account, click on “Sign Out” otherwise click the “Create Apple ID” button (alternatively, you can sign up on the web directly from Apple)
Agree to the Terms and Conditions and fill out the Apple ID creation page, set this up for a new email address than your primary app store account

At the “Provide a Payment Method” screen, select “None” as the payment option
Optionally, add a gift certificate to pad the account with an app purchase budget
Click “Create Apple ID” and verify the email address you provided earlier, your credit card free Mac App Store login is now active

Now log into the App Store with the newly created Apple ID and the user will be able to download any free apps or download updates to existing apps.